# Get value from select list in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, select, getelementbyid

I know that this might be very simple question and I tried to find solutions in the web but I can't figure it...
I have the following C# / ASPX code:

```
    SelectArea += "<select name=\"Area\" id=\"area\">" + "<option value=\"Default\" style=\"display:none;\">SELECT AREA</option>";
    for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        AreaName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AreaName"].ToString();
        SelectArea += string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\"/>{0}</option>", AreaName);
    }
    SelectArea += "</select>";
```

And this javascript function that happeen after submit

```
function validateProfile() {

    var el = document.getElementById("area").value;
    alert(el);
}
```

I want some how to get the number of the selected value in the list.
I tried with the code above but it doesn't work.

wish for help, thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious. Is there a reason not to use DropDownList Server Control?

Comment: Hi, Yes you right, it is better to use  DropDownList Server Control *but* in this work there is specific request to do that like this.

Comment: Trivial but you could use single quotes: `"<select name='Area' id='area'><option value='Default' style='display:none;'>SELECT AREA</option>";` for that string

Comment: Thanks, good advice (didn't know this befor ;), but someone knoes how to solve this??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example if you have

```
  <select id="myselect">
      <option value="1">value1</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">value2</option>
      <option value="3">value3</option>
  </select>
```

To get selected option do:

```
  var selects = document.getElementById("myselect");
  var selectedValue = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].value;// will gives u 2
  var selectedText = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].text;// gives u value2
```

Sample [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqHs5/)

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but in your JS code I get this error message "cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined", why?

Comment: To someone who wants to do this easily just do this `let value = document.querySelector('#myselect').value;`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
var el = document.getElementById("area");
var selectedArea = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thanks bit it gets undifined value, why?

Comment: @NaveTseva: what's the value of `el.selectedIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var myList = document.getElementById("area");
var selectedValue = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I get the error message : cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined 

why?

Comment: did you put your code in **window.onload** event : 
window.onload = function() {
var myList = document.getElementById("area");
 var selectedValue =myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
 var selectedText =myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].text;  
 alert(selectedText);
}
With this html code : 
<select id="area">
  <option value="1">Item1</option>
  <option value="2">Item2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Item3</option>
</select>

Comment: Now, I didn't put the javascript in Window onload event