# Combine javascript and highcharter in R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny

I'm using the new highchart r package from [Joshua Kunst](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter). I have successfully edited one of his [examples](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/oldindex.html#draggable-points) in Shiny:

server.r:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$Macroplot2 <- renderHighchart({
    inputname<-input$name
    #h
    hc<-highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(animation = FALSE) %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Macro data") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories=as.character(1:5),#tickInterval=4,#type='datetime',
               labels=list(rotation=45),
               plotBands=list(list(label=list(text='Forecast period',align='center',verticalAlign='top'),color="#edf2f7",from=0,to=2),
                              list(label=list(text='Calibration period',align='center',verticalAlign='top'),color="#ffffff",from=3,to=4)
               )) %>% 
      hc_yAxis(
        list(
          title = list(text = "Loss"),
          align = "left",
          showFirstLabel = FALSE,
          showLastLabel = FALSE#,
          #labels = list(format = "{value} &#176;C", useHTML = TRUE)
        ),
        list(
          title = list(text = inputname),
          align = "right",
          showFirstLabel = FALSE,
          showLastLabel = FALSE,
          #labels = list(format = "{value} mm"),
          opposite = TRUE
        ),
        list(
          title = list(text = "two"),
          align = "right",
          showFirstLabel = FALSE,
          showLastLabel = FALSE,
          #labels = list(format = "{value} mm"),
          opposite = TRUE
        )
      ) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(
          #stickyTracking = FALSE,
          point = list(
            events = list(
              drop = JS("function(){
                        console.log(this.series)

                        window.data = _.map(this.series.data, function(e) { return e.y })
                        if(this.series.name==document.getElementById('name').value){Shiny.onInputChange('line1', data)}
                        else {Shiny.onInputChange('line2', data)}
}"))
              ))) %>% 

      hc_add_series(name = inputname, type = 'line', color = 'red',
                    #data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
                    data=c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2),yAxis=1,
                    draggableY = TRUE

      )%>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "One", type = 'line', color = 'blue',
                    #data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
                    data=c(14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5),yAxis=2,
                    draggableY = TRUE
      )  %>%             

      hc_add_series(name =paste0('Loss'), type = 'line', color = 'black',
                    #data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))
                    data=c(1:5),
                    draggableY = FALSE)





              })

  output$table <-renderDataTable({

    if(is.null(input$line1)) var <-   c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2) else var <- input$line1
    if(is.null(input$line2)) var2 <- c(14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5) else var2 <- input$line2

    #var <- var[(length(var)-input$n.ahead+1):length(var)]
    #Output from graph

  table <-  data.table(var,var2)#Here I want to use the dragged data. something linke input$highchart$... should do the trick I guess...
  names(table)<-c('One',input$name)
  table
    })

  })
```

ui.r:

```
 library(shiny)
  library(highcharter)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(  


  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      selectInput("name",label = "name",choices = c("First","Second"),selected = "First"),
      # plotOutput("distPlot"),
      highchartOutput("Macroplot2")
      ,dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
))
```

I want to parse the `input$name` inside the javascript code which I tried with `document.getElementById('name').value` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719412/get-value-from-select-list-in-js) and I also tried `$('#name').val()` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box). So I want that if I drag the line that is either named First or Second, the table changes accordingly.